# 'google' is not defined in IE when using Google Maps

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps

I'm having trouble with Internet Explorer when trying to use Google Maps. It works fine in all other browsers, but in IE (I've tested in 6 & 7), it says `'google' is not defined`.

I assume this is due to the Google Maps script not being loaded properly, as I'm also having exactly the same problem with RPXNow (`'RPXNOW' is not defined`). How can I force IE to wait for the scripts to finish loading?

Comment: You could fire up Fiddler and see if the script url request is pulling the file down properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the initial calling functions in another function and call that when the window loads:

```
function startup(){ ... }

if( window.addEventListener )
  window.addEventListener('load',startup,false);
else if( window.attachEvent)
  window.attachEvent('onload',startup);
else
  onload=startup;
```

This will ensure that the other resources have finished loading before the browser attempts to use them.